# What type of switches are used by impulse relays?

Tags: switches

I am looking for a switch for impulse relay. These switches are bi-stable switches and return to the original state after being pressed.  Hobby push button switches do not cut it for me because I need a more elegant solution, and I could not find google for a product or the more appropriate term. Doorbell switches are an option but is not really favorable because of the doorbell sign and sometimes its design really looks like a doorbell. I am looking for something that resembles an ordinary light switch but is mono stable.

I know it exist because in this [video](https://youtu.be/8WzzPxKV_hc?t=502) you can see the switch is used, also Schneider use these switches in their impulse relay guide, but does not even mention a product code.

I was hoping someone would know the proper search term for these switches.

Comment: Momentary action push button.

Comment: @Andyaka good sir, thank you the _momentary action_ is the key word thank you im having good results on google now, if you post that as an answer sir i will accept it.

Answer (score 2):

> I was hoping someone would know the proper search term for these
>   switches.

Momentary action push buttons.

> if you post that as an answer sir i will accept it.

Comment: @jake, I thought you were accepting this answer?

Comment: @JakeQuin, I thought you were accepting this answer?